# GWT LinkedHashMap.clone() issue

Tags: gwt, classcastexception, linkedhashmap

Faced an interesting issue recently. I've catched ClassCastException while executing this code:

```
LinkedHashMap<Tag, Boolean> tags = new LinkedHashMap<Tag, Boolean>();
...
LinkedHashMap<Tag, Boolean> tagsCopy = (LinkedHashMap<Tag, Boolean>)tags.clone();//exception on this line
```

In development mode it works just fine, but it fails in production somewhy. Solved it by creating a shallow copy manually. But I'm still interested in what caused such a behaviour.
Any ideas?

UPD forgot to mention, I use java.util.LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clone` is not supported by GWT, see [issue 1843](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1843) on the GWT issue tracker. It does work in development mode as in that mode plain Java code is executed, while in production the generated JavaScript is executed, for which no working implementation of clone is generated. In issue 1843 are some suggestions for creating a GWT compatible version, but afaik those suggestions are not in the GWT implemented.

Comment: Thank you, Hilbrand. I should have read documentation more carefully. I just saw that LinkedHashMap is supported, but didn't make sure methods I use are supported.

Answer (score 0):

With GWT 2.4, `LinkedHashMap.clone()` returns a `HashMap`. Try using `Map<...> = (Map<...>) anyOtherMap.clone();` in the general case to avoid such issues.